# Angular material dialog problems - Can't get it to open a dialog?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Can anybody spot where I am going wrong with trying to open this dialog from a button click? I already have 3 different dialogs that work perfectly, but I just can't figure out what i am doing wrong...

I have made sure to include an import of the `dialog-to-open.component.ts` file in app.module.ts and everywhere else that the others have been imported into...

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `openFullDetailDialog(r.number)` in template, but in component you only have `openFullDetailDialog()` with no arguments.

Comment: Fixed and still not working for some reason.
If I swap out the page being called when opening the dialog, it will actually open the page called - But not the new page I am wanting to show.
I am getting a console error: `Error: No component factory found for RaceDetailPopupComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Comment: It is as error suggests: did you add your component to @NgModule.entryComponents? Please refer to official documentation https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-

Comment: Yeah, I did it and it now brings the content up. I just have no idea why the other 2 dialogs that open correctly from the same element don't require this!

Answer (score 0):

since you are passing data through click event you need to import MAT_DIALOG_DATA into the my-file.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was getting the console error:

> **Error: No component factory found for RaceDetailPopupComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?**

After a bit of Googling I found that I needed to add RaceDetailPopupComponent to my 'app.module.ts' file under the `entryComponents:[]` section.

My dialog now opens properly.

*NB. I have no idea why this happened as I alread have 2 dialogs that open from the same location but with different outputs... They work without this entryComponents import.*

Comment: There's actually a section on "Configuring dialog content via `entryComponents`" where it states that it is required to pass in the dialog component to the `entryComponents` so that the Angular compiler knows how to set a `ComponentFactory` for the dialog component. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#configuring-dialog-content-via-code-entrycomponents-code-

Comment: I can understand that now I have seen it. I just don't understand why the other 2 dialogs I use do not require to be declared in the `entryComponents` section.

Comment: @Edric - It has decided this morning, that it DOES require the other pages to be triggered with the use of `entryComponents`... Strange